# Continuous function but not differentiable

Tags: calculus

$$f'(x) = 2\frac{x^{1/3}-1}{x^{1/3}}$$

critical numbers: x = 1,0

What does it mean by this function is continuous at zero, but not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Is $f'(x)$ supposed to be the derivate away from $x=0$, or is it the function that is supposed to be continuous and not differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: As a general idea (not an answer to your question), there exists functions continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. [Example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, so we say that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ (these are NOT the same things though - an example will follow later). However, by integrating $f'(x)$ we get $f(x) = 2x-3x^{2/3}$ up to a constant, which is defined everywhere. Now $x^{1/n}$ is continuous for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and polynomials are too. A composition of continuous functions is continuous, so $f$ is continuous.

Intuitively speaking, this means you could trace out the curve for $f(x)$ without lifting your pencil, but at $x=0$, you curve will have a rather sharp bend. A very common and similar example is the absolute value function $f(x) = |x|$:

[image]

There is a sharp bend at $x=0$, and the function is, in fact, not differentiable there, but for different reasons: the derivative does not "settle" down to the same value as we approach $0$ from the positive and negative direction. Note that this a different situation compared to your function - the derivative is ill-defined not because the expression has a division by $0$; indeed, there is no one expression for $f'(x)$ at $x=0$, but we rather have two, and they do not "match up". Formally, the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit of $f'(x)$ do not agree, and the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is $f(x)=2x-\frac{6}{2}x^{\frac{2}{3}}+c$ for some constant $c$. So it is continuous at $0$ and  have a derivation equals $f'(x)=2(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}})$. But $f'(x)$ is not defined at zero so $f(x)$ is not differentiable at zero.